# Translate keyboard key to keyboard combination

Tags: java, keyboard

Is there any way to achieve this?

I have a character, say "/" and I want to get the keyboard combination for this.

For the German layout, "/" would be <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know what key combination is necessary to generate a specific character. The closest I have come to this is this bit of code: [KeyboardLayout](https://code.google.com/p/windowlicker/source/browse/trunk/src/core/main/com/objogate/wl/keyboard/KeyboardLayout.java?r=244). It uses the keyboard layouts on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout) to build a map of key codes for each language.

Comment: do I understand correctly, you did save the combinations in a textfile and read them based on the keyboard locale?

Comment: No, the KeyboardLayout contains a map of Character to KeyStroke. It's not very elegant but it's the only way I've found to do it.

Comment: Yes but the special keystrokes are defined in external files and loaded into the map?!

Comment: @matthias Ignore my previous answer. Yes, the keyboard layouts are stored in text files as resources and then read in as needed